# Dynamic object layouts in Flash

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, adobe

I have a general Flash question. I have got 2 .SWF wrappers (Playbook and Android,that work perfectly) that takes any .SWF file and wraps it up as an application. I'm hoping to make 1 application and have it run on both the Blackberry Playbook and any Android device. Technically everything is perfect but the problem I am having is with the layout.

For example if an object is placed at x= 512 y=400 then it looks great on the Playbook but that looks horrible on an Android screen thats not 1024x800px. What I want to be able to do is something like (x=DeviceWidth/2), (y= DeviceHeight/2) so that it resizes and repositions itself automatically. An example of where I need to change the code is shown below

```
bt1.tween("_y", 400, 0.5, "easeOutBack");
```

Is this possible? If so what is the syntax for this or where can I find this info?

Thanks for your help

Regards

Comment: When you say "Looks horrible" are you talking about your assets or the placement?  In the context of Flex, you can layout your children / elements in updateDisplayList() which will give you the height and width of the container.  Any sizing / positioning should normally be relative to to the unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight values passed into updateDisplayList().

Comment: Sorry im referring to the placement for example if its centred on the playbook I want it to be centred on the Galaxy Tab, Xoom etc.

Comment: How are you placing the elements then?  It looks like you're using absolute positioning.  Don't.  Override updateDisplayList and calculate their positions [and potentially size] based on the space you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Flextras said is right, you can override the `updateDisplayList` function to calculate where things should go, but you're trying to use a tween (which I'm not sure why).  You can also use absolute centering (horizontalCenter=0, verticalCenter=0) if you have it contained within a Group or any other absolute based container, but it won't help with the tween.

In your case, you'll probably want to do something like this:

```
bt1.tween("_y", (stage.height - bt1.height)/2, 0.5, "easeOutBack");
```